# Convert RTF to DOCX with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am a novice at this but I convert `.RTF` files in a whole folder to `.DOCX` files using this code below.

```
Sub BatchConvertToDocx()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, wdDoc As Document
    strFolder = GetFolder
    If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.rtf", vbNormal)
    While strFile <> ""
      Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
      With wdDoc
        .SaveAs2 FileName:=Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.FullName, ".")) & "docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
      End With
      strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    App

    lication.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

Could somebody please tell me how to hide text that is between square braces in the output `.docx` file?

For example

```
Hi [This is the text that should be hidden] there.
```

Also, while converting the `.docx` file back to `.rtf` file, the text should reappear in the output `.rtf` file.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 different ways to do this.

1. Hard remove/delete the text with find/replace. Here I see no possibility to bring that text back in any way. Gone is gone.
2. Hide the text from printing with formatting it as hidden text.

**Hard Remove**

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "\[*\]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

**Hide from printing**

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Hidden = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "\[*\]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

'if this line is not used the text might be visible on the screen but not on print.
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = False
```

**Unhiding the text from printing**
This should un hide the text when converting back to `.rtf`

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Hidden = True
Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Hidden = False
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "\[*\]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: thanks Peh, where do I add this to the parent code? As I said I am a novice :)

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is not a free code writing service nor a site to teach you coding VBA (for this purpose there are other websites). I can only show up possibilities or techniques. If you need a full working code then this is the wrong place. My answer above is just a show case 'how it could be done' not a ready to use solution.